# Number of outcomes for 6 dice to get 3 different numbers appearing twice

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to find a solution for a HW problem where I need to find the number of outcomes for 6 dice to get 3 different numbers appearing twice.

My attempt:
6C3 ( number of ways to choose these 3 distinct numbers) times

6C2 (the number of ways the first repeated number can show up among the six dice) times

6C2 the number of ways the second repeated number can show up among the remaining six slots

= (5 ×15 ×15)

I am not sure of the answer and any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the dice are distinguishable, there are $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to select which three numbers each appear twice, $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to select on which two dice the smallest number appears, $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to select on which two of the remaining four dice the next smallest number appears, and one way to assign the remaining two dice the remaining number.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2} = 20 \cdot 15 \cdot 6 = 1800$$
outcomes in which three different numbers each appear twice when six distinguishable six-sided dice are rolled.

Comment: I think I fail to understand something very fundumental here and wonder if you can put some light into it. If the dice is rolled 6 times what type of combo can you have that there are 3 different numbers appearing twice? I was thinking on paraphrasing this question such that: you have the following word: AAAAAABBBBBBCCCCCCDDDDDDEEEEEEFFFFFF in how many ways you can have a 3 letter word where 2 letter appears twice (not sure if this is an equivalent question) wonder if you can assist me understanding the basic of 'get 3 different number appearing twice' with an example. Thank you

Comment: @adhg A sequence of rolls in which three numbers each appear twice is 2, 5, 5, 3, 2, 3.  In my approach, I chose which three numbers appear in the sequence and chose which two locations in the sequence each number appears.  In the example, the three numbers we choose are 2, 3, and 5.  We then choose to place the 2's in positions 1 and 5, the 3's in positions 4 and 6, and the 5's in positions 2 and 3.  The problem you posed is not equivalent to this one.

Comment: oh. I was totally off. Thank you for the clarification. I (finally) got it!